# Joomla - unable to select Intro or Full Article Image

Tags: joomla, php-5.6

Using Joomla v.3.6.5 on PHP 5.6.30.

In all articles, old or new, when I select the images and Links tab and try to assign either an Intro Image or a Full Article Image, the CMS responds with a forbidding sign when I hover or click on the form, and does nothing when I click select (instead of opening a popup image choosing menu).

I can upload or edit media folders without a problem. I can add images via the article content editor without a problem. In some older articles there are Intro Images and Full Article Images assigned but they cannot be changed, the form behavior is the same. It is only the Intro Images and Full Article Images that are forbidden/not accessible via the form.

Any pointers on what went south are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Update to the latest Joomla version 3.7.2 and PHP version 7.x

Login to Joomla backend,

Goto System --> Global Check-in --> select all the list of database tables and click Check-in.

Goto System --> Global Check-in --> Click Clear Cache --> Delete all.

Goto System --> Global Check-in --> Click Clear Expired Cache --> Click Clear Expired Cache.

Goto Extensions --> Manage --> Discover --> Click Discover.

Goto Extensions --> Manage --> Data base --> Click Fix.

Answer (score 0):

Updating to Joomla v.3.7.2 fixed the issue.